# nifi: how to change value of json?

Tags: apache-nifi

i have processor InvokeHTTP which gives json result.
for instance:

```
{
  "revision" : {
    "clientId" : "dc572274-4b71-11b6-e415-b91e391bcf4d",
    "version" : 7
  },
  "id" : "dc572260-4b71-11b6-0371-f73573ab44fe",
  "uri" : "http://x.x.x.x:9090/nifi-api/processors/dc572260-4b71-0371-73ab44fe",
  "position" : {
    "x" : -1021.9568138214972,
    "y" : 333.2029958718132
  }
}
```

i want to change the value of version dynamically for each incoming response of InvokeHTTP.
how to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Provide a MCVE

Comment: i have tried with ReplaceText processor to search for version, get its value and then use UpdateAttribute. but i am really stuck up with the SearchValue and ReplacementValue in ReplaceText processor because i am not familiar with regex.

Comment: i tried with update attribute to include version with the value of 8(static) and then replacetext with the properties of SearchValue of "(?s)(^.*$)" and ReplacementValue of "$1,"version":"${version}"". but it is getting inserted as new value at the end of the json instead of searching the version and changing the corresponding value.

Answer (score 2):

i could suggest ExecuteScript processor with `groovy` language

```java
import groovy.json.*

def ff = session.get()
if(!ff) return
ff = session.write(ff, {rawIn, rawOut->
    //parse flowfile content to maps & arrays
    def json = new JsonSlurper().parse(rawIn, "UTF-8")
    //change json 
    json.revision.version =  (json.revision.version as Long) + 1
    //write to output changed content
    rawOut.withWriter("UTF-8"){ it.write( JsonOutput.toJson(json) )}
} as StreamCallback)
session.transfer(ff, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Comment: I am getting the error saying Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: <eval>:1:0 Expected an operand but found import
import groovy.json.*
^ in <eval> at line number 1 at column number 0

Comment: did you set `groovy` as language?  in exception you provided there is two times `import` - but should be once. check the code.

Comment: it works perfectly, thanks. but it rearranges the whole json line.

Comment: is it possible to extract only some of the property of json with the same format.

Comment: normally, the order of attributes in json means nothing. instead of script you can use this sequence of processors: `EvaluateJsonPath` to get value of attribute, `UpdateAttribute` to change it, and `ReplaceText` to substitute old value in content with new one using regular expression.

Comment: i followed the same sequence of EvaluateJsonPath, UpdateAttribute, ReplaceText. it is working till UpdateAttribute. when I try to use ReplaceText, it is adding new property at the end of the line. how can we use ReplaceText to change only particular value(i.e version) and keep rest of them untouched.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this sequence of processors: `EvaluateJsonPath` to get value of attribute, `UpdateAttribute` to change it, and `ReplaceText` to substitute old value in content with new one using regular expression.

For the `ReplaceText` processor use following parameters:

`Regexp Replace` strategy

Search Value : `(?s)("version"\s*:\s*)(\d+)`

Replacement Value : `$1${VERSION}`  (where VERSION is an attribute name that holds new value)

Here is a nice resource to test the regular expressions: 
https://regex101.com/r/JOrZNp/1